# JavaFX URLConnection connect() throws error only in packaged app but works in debug

Tags: java, windows, swing, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm not able to connect to the internet from my packaged `Javafx` application. It works perfectly in development. I'm using gradle `jlink` and `jpackage` to create a Windows executable. The application installs successfully but it seems the `URLConnection connect()` method is throwing an error.

What possibly could be the reason this is happening only after the application has been packaged and installed?.

Also, there seem not to be enough resources out there to help, I'd appreciate if someone can better enlighten me. This is my first time packaging a JavaFX app

Comment: What is the url? Is it https? Do you [need cryptoki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74628587/beryx-badass-runtime-tlsv1-3-javax-net-ssl-sslprotocolexception-received-close/74649649#74649649)?

Comment: Or maybe jdk.crypto.ec needed for SSL/TLS/HTTPS to many servers today; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379520/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73590370/ and more linked there

Comment: @jewelsea, the link helped. I was able to fix the issue by adding jdk.crypto.cryptoki to the module-info.java

Comment: @Urchboy Please post and accept an Answer to your own Question, with the interesting and relevant details.