# Do I Need To Package the Windows dlls With A JavaFX Application?

Tags: javafx

I downloaded the latest version of JavaFX from the Gluon website and extracted the zipped SDK. As well as the /lib directory that stores the jars I also see a /bin directory packed full with various dlls. If I build a Java/JavaFX application and bundle it using Maven then do I need to also bundle these dlls? And if so, then do a similar process of shipping native libs for Linux and Mac? Or, can I just get away with packaging the jars?
Thanks.

Comment: there's a whole section about deploying fx applications in the tag wiki - make sure you study them :)

Comment: Just in case you can't find it: Go to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info and then scroll down to "Packaging".

Comment: You need the native code. The JARs from Maven Central embed this native code, but that also means JavaFX first has to extract the native libraries to a location on the host's computer before they can be used (typically under the user's home directory). Also, deploying a JavaFX application as a JAR is not the best way. It's better to create a self-contained application package using e.g., `jlink` and `jpackage` (with those tools it's [better to use the JMOD files provided by Gluon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61294243/running-javafx-application-after-jpackage/61294909#61294909)).