# Possible to create Windows Installer / MacOS Native App

Tags: java, maven, javafx, netbeans

I have created a Maven JavaFX (Java SE SDK 18.0.2, JavaFX 18.0.2) project in Netbeans 15. I have a project with several dependencies (from Maven repositories). Now, I wish to package the project as a Windows Installer and MacOS dmg. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at `jlink` + `jpackage` ([User Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/jpackage/packaging-overview.html)). Also check out [JPackageScriptFX](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX) and the FAQ's under the "Packaging" section of the [JavaFX tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info). If you do end up using `jlink` + `jpackage` then I recommend [using the JMOD files of JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61294243/6395627).

Comment: There's also [GraalVM's native image](https://www.graalvm.org/22.2/reference-manual/native-image/). Check out https://gluonhq.com/create-native-javafx-applications-using-graalvm-22-builds-from-gluon/