# How and where can I download JavaFX on M1 Mac?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I've been trying to download JavaFX for a project and my laptop is just not having it when I try to gradle run.

I can gradle build just fine but when I try gradle run I get this message:

```
> Configure project :
Project : => no module-info.java found

> Task :run FAILED
Loading library prism_es2 from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/claretian/.openjfx/cache/20+19/aarch64/libprism_es2.dylib: dlopen(/Users/claretian/.openjfx/cache/20+19/aarch64/libprism_es2.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/claretian/.openjfx/cache/20+19/aarch64/libprism_es2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/claretian/.openjfx/cache/20+19/aarch64/libprism_es2.dylib: dlopen(/Users/claretian/.openjfx/cache/20+19/aarch64/libprism_es2.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/claretian/.openjfx/cache/20+19/aarch64/libprism_es2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:331)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:197)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:139)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2404)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:817)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:2015)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.installLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:217)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:197)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:138)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:54)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.lambda$static$0(ES2Pipeline.java:63)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:52)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:391)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:382)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:92)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Loading library prism_sw from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/claretian/.openjfx/cache/20+19/aarch64/libprism_sw.dylib: dlopen(/Users/claretian/.openjfx/cache/20+19/aarch64/libprism_sw.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/claretian/.openjfx/cache/20+19/aarch64/libprism_sw.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/claretian/.openjfx/cache/20+19/aarch64/libprism_sw.dylib: dlopen(/Users/claretian/.openjfx/cache/20+19/aarch64/libprism_sw.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/claretian/.openjfx/cache/20+19/aarch64/libprism_sw.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:331)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:197)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:139)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2404)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:817)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:2015)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.installLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:217)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:197)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:138)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:54)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.lambda$static$0(SWPipeline.java:43)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.<clinit>(SWPipeline.java:42)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:391)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:382)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:92)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:263)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:275)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        ... 2 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/Users/claretian/.sdkman/candidates/java/20.0.2-amzn/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

I'm pretty sure it's to do with the architecture being incompatible but I've tried to download every version of JavaFX I could find.

Comment: Did you start at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction

Comment: I used https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/. macOS aarch64 Version

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

You seem to have two problems:

- Missing `module-java.java` file necessary for a modularized app
- Wrong installation of JavaFX, for Intel chips rather than Apple Silicon chips like the M1.

## Modularize

Apparently some part of your configuration, or some library, expects your project to be modularized per [Java Platform Module System (JPMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System). I say this because of your error:

> Project : => no module-info.java found

The `module-java.java` file is where you specify your module configuration. Apparently you do not have one.

## Obtaining JavaFX technology

Three routes to accessing JavaFX:

- Manually download JavaFX implementation. See the [Gluon downloads page](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/).
- Have Gradle download libraries, to be a part of your development project
- Develop and deploy using a JDK that comes bundled with the JavaFX/OpenJFX libraries

For someone starting out dabbling with JavaFX, I suggest the bundled-with-JDK option.

### Download libraries

You *can* tell [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) to download the necessary [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/) libraries that implement [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX).

One easy way to do that is to use the JavaFX new-project template bundled with [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).

[image: screenshot of IntelliJ new-project template dialog for JavaFX]

After updating the version numbers to the latest, your `build.gradle` file might look like the following.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.26.0'
}

group 'work.basil.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.10.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = '20'
targetCompatibility = '20'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'work.basil.example.exfx'
    mainClass = 'work.basil.example.exfx.HelloApplication'
}

javafx {
    version = '20.0.2'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
```

**CAUTION…** One major problem with the Gradle version of IntelliJ’s new-project template for JavaFX: The project is not modularized for [Java Platform Module System (JPMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System). This may be okay for dabbling with JavaFX. But for professional development, you will likely want your project to be modularized so you can use [*jlink*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/282) to bundle a slimmed-down JVM as part of your final app artifact. This lack of modularization surprised me as the Maven edition of their new-project template does indeed produce a project already configured to be modularized.

### JDK bundled with JavaFX

At least two of the several JDK vendors provide an edition of the JDK products that include the necessary OpenJFX libraries that implement JavaFX.

- *ZuluFX* by [Azul Systems](https://www.azul.com/) ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems))
- *LibericaFX* by [BellSoft](https://bell-sw.com/)

Those companies may also sell support for JavaFX, as might the co-leaders of JavaFX, Gluon and Oracle.

To most easily download and install these JDKs, I suggest installing [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/) on your Mac. That handy bundle of shell scripts makes the download/install/uninstall chore quite simple and convenient. Just run this:

```bash
% sdk install java 17.0.8.fx-zulu
```

… to get this:

```bash
Downloading: java 17.0.8.fx-zulu

In progress...

########################################################################################################################### 100.0%

Repackaging Java 17.0.8.fx-zulu...

Done repackaging...

Installing: java 17.0.8.fx-zulu
Done installing!

Do you want java 17.0.8.fx-zulu to be set as default? (Y/n): Y
```

To see a list of all JDK products available via SDKMAN!, run this:

```bash
sdk list java
```

## Native code

Be aware that JavaFX is *not* pure Java. The needed libraries contain some native code specific to the particular host [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), and specific to the particular host machine’s chip ([instruction set architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture)).

For your [M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon#Apple_M1) Mac, you need an edition of JavaFX for [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) running on Macs with [Apple Silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon). You may see options for [*aarch64*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AArch64) or [*ARM*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture_family), which are compatible with Apple Silicon.

- I am guessing Gradle must automatically detect your host environment and download the appropriate version.
- If using the bundled-with-JDK route, for your particular Mac, be sure to obtain an edition for macOS on Apple Silicon/aarch65/ARM rather than for Intel/x64/x86-64 in older Macs.

Your error message suggests that you have indeed installed for the wrong chip architecture:

> mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)

Comment: "_Project : => no module-info.java found_" – That comes from the `org.javamodularity.moduleplugin` plugin, which is implicitly applied by the `org.openjfx.javafxplugin` plugin, by the way. And it's actually the latter plugin that handles downloading the correct JavaFX artifact for the current platform (detected via [osdetector-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/google/osdetector-gradle-plugin)). Note this implemented using classifiers and works better in Maven, as transitive dependency resolution appears to break in Gradle when using classifiers.

Comment: That's why I consider the Gradle JavaFX plugin _required_ when developing a JavaFX application with Gradle (unless you're using a JDK that includes JavaFX). Though I've always wondered if Gradle's so-called "variants" would make it easier to work with JavaFX in Gradle. Not very familiar with that feature, however, and it would require changes to the OpenJFX build file(s), if I understand correctly.

Comment: "_For someone starting out dabbling with JavaFX, I suggest the bundled-with-JDK option_" – If viable, I would suggest using the bundled-with-JDK option always, as then `jlink` / `jpackage` will implicitly use the JMOD files of the JavaFX modules. Otherwise, you have to download them from Gluon and point to them manually. [Using the JMOD files is "cleaner" than the native-code-embedded-in-JARs Maven artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61294909/6395627). The embedded approach requires extracting the native code (done automatically) before it can be used.

Comment: "_But for professional development, you will likely want your project to be modularized so you can use jlink to bundle_" – Not always practical, as many libraries have yet to go modular, if they ever will. There are tools that attempt to make non-modular deps into modular deps while packaging an application, but I don't know how well that works. Though I want to point out this is only a problem when _only_ using `jlink`. The `jpackage` tool can work with non-modular applications (meaning you can have some deps, e.g., JavaFX, in the run-time image, and put everything else on the class-path).

Comment: @Slaw May I suggest you create a Question and Answer to explain your points raised here? Building a JavaFX app for deployment is a complex and confusing process that desperately needs better documentation.

Comment: For reference, [`https://jdk.java.net`](https://jdk.java.net) hosts recent OpenJDK builds for both x86 and AArch64.

Comment: Well, interestingly it looks like the Gradle plugin has [been updated](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin/releases/tag/0.1.0) to use Gradle variants.

Comment: @Slaw's comment is valid. Try using Netty in a JavaFX modular project and you'll find both jlink and JavaFX's Maven jlink plugin complain that it doesn't work with non-module automatic libs. Then try generating the module-info descriptor using ModTect, and good luck :-) and then also add non-module libs argparse4j and usb4java, etc into your project. That's with J21 and modules were added way back in J9.

Comment: @GrahamSeed Yes, it's unfortunate many libraries won't update to add a module-info descriptor. Though just want to make sure it's clear that you should still be able to use a tool like `jpackage` (you can mix `--module-path` / `--add-modules` for those dependencies you want in the run-time image with `--input` / `--main-jar` for everything that needs to be on the class-path).